# Why when I comment the line where I enabled stdscr.nodelay() nothing changes?

Tags: python, python-3.6, curses, python-curses

I'm coding a snake game... yes, I know, how original.

My problem is the following:
I enabled nodelay() by writing `stdscr.nodelay(1)` and then I did set the timeout() to 100 miliseconds by writing `stdscr.timeout(100)`. Happens what I expected. Everything fine.

But when I comment the line where I enabled nodelay() by adding a `#` right at the beginning of the line to see what will happen, nothing changes when I execute my program. Why???

```
import curses
from curses import textpad
from constants import *

def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
#    stdscr.nodelay(1)
    stdscr.timeout(int(1000 / 15))

    screen_height, screen_width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    if screen_height < 40 or screen_width < 168:
        raise ValueError("Your terminal screen must be 40 rows and 168 columns minimum. ")

    snake = [
        [screen_height // 2, screen_width // 2]
    ]

    stdscr.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], "#")    

    direction = None

    while True:
        key = stdscr.getch()

        if direction == curses.KEY_RIGHT or key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            snake[0][1] += 1
            direction = curses.KEY_RIGHT

        if direction == curses.KEY_LEFT or key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            snake[0][1] -= 1
            direction = curses.KEY_LEFT

        if direction == curses.KEY_UP or key == curses.KEY_UP:
            snake[0][0] -= 1
            direction = curses.KEY_UP

        if direction == curses.KEY_DOWN or key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            snake[0][0] += 1
            direction = curses.KEY_DOWN

        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], "#")    

curses.wrapper(main)
```

What I expected to happen is that the program now will wait for user's input everytime I do a stdscr.getch()

But what actually happens is that the program acts like nodelay is still enabled, so it doesnt wait for any input

Answer (score 1):

[`timeout`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-timeout_wtimeout) does something similar to [`nodelay`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay):

> The **`timeout`** and **`wtimeout`** routines set blocking or non-blocking read for
>          a given window.

versus

> The **`nodelay`** option causes getch to be a non-blocking call.

(you may not notice the difference between something less than a tenth of a second and no delay at all).

Comment: What happens if I don't write any timeout stuff and only write stdscr.nodelay(1), then?

Comment: The most recent call wins (both set **`_delay`** in ncurses' `WINDOW` structure).

Comment: When we are speaking about "calls", we are referring to stdscr.getch(), right?